# How to create MongoDB connector to power bi in docker image?

Tags: java, mongodb

I already create image for MongoDB which is working fine but not able to connect to power bi using OBDC connector.

How to create MongoDB connector to power bi in docker image?

Comment: I understand that you need a ODBC connector for MongoDB. Find one here: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/odbc-connector-for-mongodb

Comment: Also this `bi-connector`? https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector

Comment: i need ODBC connector for mongodb which is a docker image. i already checked the link provided but cannot able to connect to power bi

Comment: can we use odbc connector for mongodb which is a docker image.